# IText PDF Signature

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

I want to digitally sign the pdf and the straightforward option is the itext. I am just appending a signature incase there is a first one. But when members view it , it shows unknow with error `Error information : Error during signature verification. Signature contains incorrect ,unrecognized, corrupted or suspicious data. Support information SigDict/Contents illegal data`. what can I do?

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.StampingProperties;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.*;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;

public class App {

        public static void digitalSignature(String sourceFile, String signatureFieldName, String outputFile, Certificate[] certificateChain, PrivateKey privateKey, String digestAlgorithm,
                                            String bouncyCastleProvider, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard cryptoStandardSubFilter, String reason, String location)
                throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
                PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(outputFile), new StampingProperties());

                // Create the signature appearance
                PdfSignatureAppearance pdfSignatureAppearance = pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance()
                        .setReason(reason)
                        .setLocation(location);

                // This name corresponds to the name of the field that already exists in the document.
                pdfSigner.setFieldName(signatureFieldName);

                pdfSignatureAppearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);

                IExternalSignature iExternalSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(privateKey, digestAlgorithm, bouncyCastleProvider);
                IExternalDigest iExternalDigest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

                // Sign the document using the detached mode, CMS, or CAdES equivalent.
                pdfSigner.signDetached(iExternalDigest, iExternalSignature, certificateChain, null, null, null, 0, cryptoStandardSubFilter);
        }

        
}
```

I would appreciate any help. I have used alot of time in this. The purpose is actually to add a second signature to the document for verification purpose. I don't want the option for creating/copy of this document since the first signature might get lost.

Comment: Are you signing in append mode? That is necessary to not break earlier signatures.

Comment: @mkl Sounds like it "I am just appending a signature incase there is a first one"

Comment: I think you need to correctly apply the signature then you won't get this error* 
(* please note that this comment contains the exact same amount of information you did provide)

Comment: @Lonzak *"Sounds like it"* - Yes, it sounds like that... But I've also seen people here who have read somewhere that they need to 'append' without knowing what that means, and these people then later said they 'appended signatures' without actually working in append mode.

Comment: @Law Nonetheless, as Lonzak already indicated, with the meager amount of information you give we can only answer your "what can I do?" question with : Fix your code.

Comment: Here is my code for that. The first signature is preserved well and second one added but getting that error . I am just editing the question with the code

Comment: You use plain `new StampingProperties()` when instantiating the `PdfSigner`. Thus, **you *don't* append** the signature but add it in a way that mixes up any earlier signatures. Please try `new StampingProperties().useAppendMode()` instead.

Comment: @mkl thank you for noticing that. It just helped remove the error and now the signature is not considered corrupt but only raising the error `At least one signature has a problems` which I think the reason is Adobe flagging it because it is not in `AATL` unless there is another thing I can do then I believe until a user turns the trust certificate for my signature.

Comment: Indeed, unless issued by an AATL or EUTL CA certificates usually are not trusted

Comment: Can you add this as an answer? This will help other developers as well...Thank you

Comment: I can't see the mark for accepting it. maybe @mkl could write it as answer then i accept instead of it being a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, you use plain `new StampingProperties()` when instantiating the `PdfSigner`:

```
PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader,
    new FileOutputStream(outputFile), new StampingProperties());
```

Thus, you don't *append* the signature but add it in a way that mixes up any earlier signatures. Please try `new StampingProperties().useAppendMode()` instead:

```
PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader,
    new FileOutputStream(outputFile), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
```

In response you confirmed that that worked and remarked:

> It just helped remove the error and now the signature is not considered corrupt but only raising the error `At least one signature has a problems` which I think the reason is Adobe flagging it because it is not in `AATL` unless there is another thing I can do then I believe until a user turns the trust certificate for my signature.

Indeed, unless issued by an AATL or EUTL CA, certificates usually are not trusted.

In case of company internal usage, trust for custom CA certificates may be rolled out to all computers by the IT department. Beyond that, though, go for certificates issued by an AATL or EUTL CA.